Forward-Backward Algorithm for Autoregressive HMMs
I am currently studying HMMs, and covered the Forward-Backward Algorithms as well as the smoothing and filtering process. Recently, we were posed a question on Autoregressive HMMs which I've been trying to figure out to no avail.

We were asked what the forward, backward, and forward-backwards equations in this case is. I am not too sure how to do this in this case. Do we just add a likelihood that factors in $x_{t-1}$ for each of the timestep such that our forward message is now this:
$$\alpha_{t+1}(z_{t+1})=\sum_{z_t=1}^{K}\alpha_{t}p(\mathbf{x}_{t}|z_{t})p(z_{t+1}|z_{t})\underset{\text{added term}}{p(z_{t+1}|x_{t})}$$
Thank you so much for any of the help rendered :)
